# Call jquery $.ajax inside Javascript function

Tags: jquery

I want to call an ajax function to do some stuff...

```
function RemoveTest(subfolder)
{
    var datastring="name="+subfolder;
    alert(datastring);
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mystuff.php",
    data: datastring,
        success: function(msg){
           alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
               // some suff there
        }
    }); 
}


<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="RemoveTest('test')">Click Me</a>
```

I am unable to use this please tell me how to do this.... and which jQuery file i have to include..

Comment: Please specify what doesn't work. Also, there should be only one jQuery file to include. If in doubt, show the head section of your page

Comment: have you included jQuery framework at all ?

Comment: Are you using any other javascript library other than jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using any library other thanjQuery which uses `$` then make sure that there is no conflict. See **[jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)**. Also make sure that you refer your jQuery file at the top before calling any jQuery functions.

Also if you want to create event handlers for dynamically crated anchor tags, then better give them a class name and a data attribute, something like

```
<a href='#' class='democlass' data-id='yourvalue'>Click me</a>

$("a.democlass").live("click", function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, used AJAX and solved the problem.

```
function connect(num) {
    var x = document.getElementById('myBtn');

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "request-connect.php?id="+num
    })

    modal.style.display = "block";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="RemoveTest('test')">Click Me</a>
```

to

```
<a id="link">Click Me</a>
```

and JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#link").click(function(){
 var datastring="name="+subfolder;
    alert(datastring);
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mystuff.php",
    data: datastring,
        success: function(msg){
           alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
               // some suff there
        }
    })
});

});
```

Comment: $("a").click and pass attribute "rel" on links with Folder Name, like <a href="" id="test" rel="FOlder">Click</a> or use Folder as ID of Link

Comment: <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick="MyTest()">Click me</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function MyTest() {
  //alert("test");
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'removelist.php',            
            data: 'name=test',            
            success: function(msg){ 
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){

                alert('error');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
This script always raise error on alert.. where is the proble. the file path is correct.